# char * и const char *

Tags: c, указатели

Решил вернуться к СИ и прочитать книгу K&R, и вот опять споткнулся на теме указателей, по логике вроде все понятно, но вот именно с `char *` и `const char *` какие-то проблемы.

Давайте я приведу код и покажу что мне все такие не ясно!

**Пример 1:**

```
char *pstr = "Hello, world";
*pstr = 'D'; /// При запуске приложения на этом месте вылетит сбой не понятно!
printf(pstr); /// Ну и конечно ничего не выведет, измененную строку я не получу, ой точнее массив из символов
```

**Пример 2:**

```
const char *pstr = "Hello, world";
*pstr = 'D'; /// Сбоя не будет и программа вообще не скомпилируется т.к компилятор сообщит что мы не можем изменять наш константный объект
printf(pstr); /// До сюда дело не дойдет
```

**Пример 3:**

```
char str[] = "Hello, world";
char *pstr = str;
*pstr = 'D'; /// Все ок мы успешно поменяем наш первый элемент массива
printf(pstr); /// Мы получим это: "Dello, world"
```

Подведем черту над всеми этими примерами:
Почему я не могу в первом примере поменять отдельно каждый литерал? (Я же не объявлял объект константным как во втором примере)

P.S Третий пример привел для общей картины чтобы показать что все работает если ввести дополнительный параметр

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В первом и втором случае вы работаете напрямую со *строковым литералом*.

В языке С у вас нет никакого контроля над const-квалификацией типа строкового литерала. Эта const-квалификация однозначно определяется языком. Тип строкового литерала в C - `char [N]`. И несмотря на то, что тип строкового литерала формально не содержит квалификатора `const`, строковый литерал тем не менее является *неизменяемым* (немодифицируемым) объектом. Попытки изменения строкового литерала, как и любого другого немодифицируемого объекта, ведут к неопределенному поведению.

Как вы объявляли свой указатель `pstr` - c `const` или без - на тип и свойства строкового литерала никакого влияния не оказывает. Ваш указатель не имеет никакого отношения к строковому литералу, как таковому. Ваш указатель - это не более чем *путь доступа* (access path) к реальному объекту. Константность пути доступа - это не более чем элемент самодисциплины, который в общем случае не связан с константностью объекта, к которому этот путь ведет. Язык С предоставляет вам средства для легального создания как константных путей доступа к модифицируемым объектам, так и неконстантных путей доступа к немодифицируемым объектам

```
int a = 42;
const int *pa = &a;   // константный путь доступа к модифицируемому объекту

const int b = 5;
int *pb = (int *) &b; // неконстантный путь доступа к немодифицируемому объекту
```

В конечном итоге возможность легальной модификации объекта определяется именно и только модифицируемостью самого объекта и никак не зависит от константности пути доступа к нему (ибо последняя легко устранима).

Учитывая, что литерал является неизменяемым объектом, указывать на строковые литералы неконстантным указателем (как в вашем первом примере) никакого смысла нет, даже если язык и позволяет формально это делать.

В третьем варианте вы не работаете со строковым литералом напрямую, а создаете собственный модифицируемый массив, который только *инициализируется* значением строкового литерала. Т.е. ваш массив содержит самостоятельную копию значения строкового литерала. Это ваш собственный массив и вы можете модифицировать его как угодно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50737/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-char--const-char).

Answer (score 3):

Согласно стандарту языка C (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

То есть вы не можете менять строковые литералы, несмотря на то, что они имеют типы не константных символьных массивов. То, что в C строковые литералы имеют тип неконстантных массивов, это сделано для обратной совместимости программ на C.

Поэтому в этом предложении

```
char *pstr = "Hello, world";
```

строковый литерал, используемый в качестве инициализатора указателя `pstr`, неявно преобразуется в указатель с типом `char *`, а не в указатель типа `const char *`, который указывает на первый символ литерала.

В С++ строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов, что позволяет избежать недоразумения.

В третьем примере

```
char str[] = "Hello, world";
char *pstr = str;
*pstr = 'D';
```

указатель `pstr` имеет уже дело не со строковым литералом, а с определенным пользователем символьным массивом. Строковый литерал лишь используется для инициализации элементов символьного массива своими символами. Так как массив объявлен как не константный, то его элементы можно изменять.

Comment: А можно ли как-то инициализировать указатель только типа int?

Answer (score 3):

[с](/questions/tagged/%d1%81) не достаточно типобезопасен и допускает присваивание неконстантным указателям адрес строкового литерала. То, что в левой части указатель не является константным отнюдь не значит, что можно менять то, на что он указывает. Присваивание указателю не создаёт дополнительного объекта под строку и не копирует в неё правую часть.

Т.о. Ваш код вида:

```
char *pstr = "Hello, world";
*pstr = 'D';
```

по сути эквивалентен такому (более очевидному для демонстрации варианту):

```
"Hello, world"[0] = 'D';
```

В таком виде даже *gcc* сообщает соответствующим предупреждением:

> warning: assignment of read-only location '"Hello, world"[0]'

Стандарт [с](/questions/tagged/%d1%81) однозначно утверждает, что попытка модифицировать строковый литерал приводит к неопределённому поведению (6.4.5/7):

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Строковый литерал является константным по определению. Он может быть вообще помещен в память "только для чтения". Например, VC++ в первом примере код пропустит, сбоев не будет - но при выполнении строка не изменится.

Comment: хмм, я слышал про это! то есть хоть мы и не указали спецификатор const, компилятор все равно будет думать будто он у нас указан? но почему в таком случае это не выдает ошибку?

Comment: Это уж пусть специалисты по стандартам пояснят. У меня есть подозрение, что причины сугубо исторические, но это не более чем мое imho :)

Comment: сбои вобще-то будут - модификация строкого литерала это неопределённое поведение, и программа при запуске должна аварийно завершится.

Comment: @ampawd Неопределенное поведение и аварийное завершение все же разные вещи. А с VC++ - проверено многократно...

Comment: @Harry это связанные вещи, при возникновении неопределённого  поведения (например в этом случае) ОС обычно это отлавливает и завершает программу авайрийно. я незнаю что у вас проверено, но у меня на visual studio 2015 происходит сбой (или run time error, crashing, etc)

Comment: @ampawd Значит, мне не так везет :) Скомпилируйте, пожалуйста, и запустите `#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ char* p = "Hello"; p[0]='D'; puts(p); }`. VC++ 2015. UB есть, крэша нет :) Вы все же приписываете UB **аварийность**, хотя это может быть всего лишь не то значение переменной, которого вы ожидаете...

Comment: @Harry запустил - получил крэш :) видимо что то на уровне ОС происходит, я на семёрке

Comment: @Harry UB к аварийному завершению я приписываю только в случае с модификацией строкого литерала, но никак не в общем случае UB

Comment: @ampawd Windows 7 x64, Максимальная SP1, ключи компиляции - только /O2 (без него просто выводит "Dello"). Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.00.24215.1 для x86. Компиляция 64-разрядного дает тот же результат. Или вы компилируете и запускаете из IDE?