# Ошибки C2440 / E0513

Tags: c++

Учу С++. Дошел до классов. Не получается запустить код: выбивает ошибки C2440 и E0513.
Проблему выдает в строке 16 `Test::Test() {age = 0; name="";}`
Если необходимо, то вот целый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Test 
{
private:
    int age;
    char* name;
public:
    Test();
    void printDATA();
    void inputDATA();
};

Test::Test() {age = 0; name="";}

void Test::printDATA()
{
    cout << "Age: " << age << " Name: " << name;
}

void Test::inputDATA()
{
    cout << "Input ur age: " << endl;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Input ur name: " << endl;
    cin.getline(name, 256, ';');
}

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    Test T;
    cout << "Тестовая программа" << endl;
    T.inputDATA();
    T.printDATA();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А текст ошибки кто писать будет?

Comment: [E0144 значение типа “const char *” нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа “char *”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/908800), [char * и const char *](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603691). Ну и предвещая ваш следующий вопрос: `char* name; cin.getline(name, 256, ';');` прежде чем писать по адресу `name` нужно, чтобы он указывал на какую-нибудь валидную память, которую вы выделили с поощью `new`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char* name;
> ```

```
const char* name;
```

Ну или разбирайся с выделением памяти и strcpy.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в `name` тип `char*`, а литералы строк это `const char*`.

---

Для строк лучше используйте тип `string`.

Я подправил в двух местах код, чтобы с `string` работало.

Попробуйте:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Test 
{
private:
    int age;
    string name;
//  ^^^^^^^
public:
    Test();
    void printDATA();
    void inputDATA();
};

Test::Test() {age = 0; name="";}

void Test::printDATA()
{
    cout << "Age: " << age << " Name: " << name;
}

void Test::inputDATA()
{
    cout << "Input ur age: " << endl;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Input ur name: " << endl;
    getline(std::cin, name, ';');
//  ^^^^^^^
    // cin >> name;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    Test T;
    cout << "Тестовая программа" << endl;
    T.inputDATA();
    T.printDATA();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но автор вопроса хочет читать строку, пока не наткнётся на символ `;`: `cin.getline(name, 256, ';');`

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, точно... спасибо за замечание :)